# Optimizing a nested join window function for a large Postgresql table

Tags: sql, inner-join, bigdata

I have been running the following query against a table 56GB in size (789700760 rows) and have run into a bottleneck in execution time.  From some previous examples I figured there might be a way to 'un-nest' the INNER JOIN so that the query performs better against a large data set.  In particular the query below took 7.651 hours to finish execution on a MPP PostgreSQL deployment.

```
create table large_table as
select column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6
from
(
  select 
    a.column1, a.column2, a.start_time,
    rank() OVER( 
      PARTITION BY a.column2, a.column1 order by a.start_time DESC 
    ) as rank,
    last_value( a.column3) OVER (
      PARTITION BY a.column2, a.column1 order by a.start_time ASC
      RANGE BETWEEN unbounded preceding and unbounded following 
    ) as column3,
    a.column4, a.column5, a.column6
  from 
    (table2 s 
      INNER JOIN table3 t 
      ON s.column2=t.column2 and s.event_time > t.start_time 
    ) a
 ) b
 where rank =1;
```

> Question 1: Is there a way to modify the above sql code to speed up the overall execution time of the query?

Comment: The last_value() seems redundant if the rank is returning only one row per column2, column1 combination.  Are you expecting multiple rows?  Otherwise, the value in column3 with rank = 1 should be the same as the calculated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the last_value to the outer subquery, which might buy you some improvement in performance.  The last_value is getting the value for column3 for each partition where the start time is smallest -- exactly where the rank = 1:

```
select column1, column2,
       ast_value( a.column3) OVER (PARTITION BY column2, column1 order by start_time ASC
                                   RANGE BETWEEN unbounded preceding and unbounded following
                                  ) as column3,
       column4, column5, column6
from (select a.column1, a.column2, a.start_time,
             rank() OVER (PARTITION BY a.column2, a.column1 order by a.start_time DESC
                         ) as rank,
            a.column3, a.column4, a.column5, a.column6
      from (table2 s INNER JOIN
            table3 t
            ON s.column2 = t.column2 and s.event_time > t.start_time
           ) a
     ) b
where rank = 1
```

Otherwise, you need to give more information on the execution plan and table2 and table3 to get more help.

Comment: thanks for your help I am testing the timing of the updated query but I ran into a small problem when I used the last_value(a.column3) the error given was ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "a".  I replaced the command with last_value(column3) is this still going to work?